# make nginx pass PUT requests to PHP script

Tags: windows, php, nginx, upload

I want to upload files with **PUT** request, to PHP running under NginX (windows if that matters).

PHP manual have this [instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) for *Apache*:

> A line like this would do the trick:
>   `Script PUT /put.php`

I need to do the same for NginX. I see the [$request_method](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_method) variable, not sure how to take advantage of it... Especially when NginX manual says "[if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)"...

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question & answer in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912270/how-do-i-allow-a-put-file-request-on-nginx-server).

Comment: @erny. Thanks for the link. It's related but __not__ a duplicate - SO question you mention is about uploading with WebDAV NginX module, while my question is about passing the upload through a PHP script.

Comment: Reading several sources, it seems that you don't need any special config for nginx to enable PUT request. PUT requests are send to PHP FPM. From PHP you can access the data with `$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");`. See the [PHP PUT method docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php). As the URL in a PUT request is used normally as object name, you'll have to route the URL to the corresponding controller. (There are libraries like [this one](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router) or frameworks like Yii and CakePHP which resolve this problem.)